# jQuery textbox autocomplete not showing

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete

I am new to HTML and jQuery. Recently, I am trying the autocomplete function of jQuery like [here](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).  I used the given source code except for the style.css file. Until now,

1. no autocompletion is shown when I am using Sublime Text 2 and preview it in Chrome.
2. When using the code in the code snippet provided by stackoverflow, it works fine.

How come?

Thank you.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check the console for the error

Comment: prepend `http://` in your script `src` , like `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js` & in style `src` too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) check the console for the error

2) if it throws jquery not found error correct the path

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the file on a localhost server. If you're just opening the html file in chrome it won't be able to connect to the external CSS and JS files and won't execute the other javascript in the file.

I copy pasted your code and put it on my Wamp server and it appears to be working fine for me.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Why? He's asking why it doesn't work and I replied with what I think is the reason that it doesn't work. Isn't that an answer to the question?

Comment: you're asking for a clarification, a clarification should be a comment.

Comment: @Blank Changed the wording of my answer around a bit